# How do retrieve results from various possible combinations of values for two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two arrays, one with N number of codes and another with N section ID's. The same code can be used for multiple sections and vice versa. These lists can vary in size depending on what user is logged in.

```
codes = [123, 321, 111, 222, 987]

section = [A, B, C, D]

examples: (123, A), (123, C), (321, A) (111, D)
```

I am trying to write a dynamic query (PHP using query builder in ORM) that will take in these two parameters and search for all rows that have a matching combination of the two column values.

This is what I have so far but it returns nothing.

```
SELECT sa FROM SectionAssociation sa WHERE s.code IN (:codes) AND sa.section IN (:section)
```

Comment: MySQL does not support arrays, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm using a library to build the query which does accept arrays and will translate it into the right query